# Print specific rows that are common between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe (df1) like this

```
id    link 
1     google.com
2     yahoo.com
3     gmail.com
```

i have another dataframe(df2) like this:

```
id    link           numberOfemployees   
1     linkedin.com        15
2     facebook.com        70
3     gmail.com           90
4     google.com          1000
5     twitter.com         155
6     yahoo.com           2
```

I want to write a new dataframe that contains the rows of df1 and their numberOfemployees from df2. is it feasable?

and anot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is `pd.merge` take a look at documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'link': ["google.com", "yahoo.com", "gmail.com"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    "link": ["linkedin.com","facebook.com","gmail.com","google.com","twitter.com","yahoo.com"],
                    "numberOfEmployees": [15,70,90,1000,155,2]})

df1.merge(df2, on="link", suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
```

```
------------------------------------------------------
|   |id_left |  link    |id_right | numberOfEmployees|
|---|--------|----------|---------|------------------|
|0  |1       |google.com|   4     |   1000           |
|1  |2       |yahoo.com |   6     |   2              |
|2  |3       |gmail.com |   3     |   90             |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this simple solution:

```
df2[df2.link.isin(df1.link)]
```