# Use values in a column of a df to find name from another df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes;

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"name": ["a","b","c","d","e"], "value": [0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame (data1, columns = ['name', 'value'])

data2 = {"value": [0.01,0.03,0.05]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame (data2, columns = ['value'])
```

I want to use the value in df2 to look up what its corresponding name is from df1, and add that as a new column. i.e. end up with this df:

```
data3 = {"value": [0.01,0.03,0.05], "name": ["a","c","e"]}

df3 = pd.DataFrame (data3, columns = ['value', 'name'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print specific rows that are common between two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943363/print-specific-rows-that-are-common-between-two-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
print(df2.merge(df1, on='value'))
```

Output:

```
   value name
0   0.01    a
1   0.03    c
2   0.05    e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and use it as mask in [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) here.

```
df1[df1['value'].isin(df2['value'])]

  name  value
0    a   0.01
2    c   0.03
4    e   0.05
```